# Add custom hook in prestashop's cms page in custom template

Tags: php, smarty, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm in need to create a custom hook in a specific cms page in order to show various instances of the same module (sliders of products).
I tried following this guide here http://nemops.com/how-to-hooks-prestashop-cms/#.VtbJR8Q0mdU but when I go to the backend the hook I named "Vert" doesn't show.

I'm using the latest version of prestashop, with cache disabled and I forced the 
recompilation of the tpl everytime a page is loaded.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
{hook h='displayVert'}
```

in the cms.tpl file

```
INSERT INTO `ps_hook` (`name`, `title`, `description`) VALUES ('displayVert', 'Vert', 'This is a custom hook!');
```

in phpmyadmin

```
public function install()
{
    $this->_clearCache('*');
    Configuration::updateValue('HOME_FEATURED_NBR', 8);
    Configuration::updateValue('HOME_FEATURED_CAT', (int)Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory());
    Configuration::updateValue('HOME_FEATURED_RANDOMIZE', false);

    if (!parent::install()
        || !$this->registerHook('header')
        || !$this->registerHook('addproduct')
        || !$this->registerHook('updateproduct')
        || !$this->registerHook('deleteproduct')
        || !$this->registerHook('categoryUpdate')
        || !$this->registerHook('displayHomeTab')
        || !$this->registerHook('displayHomeTabContent')
        **|| !$this->registerHook('displayVert')**
    )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

and

`public function hookdisplayVert($params){`

`if (Tools::getValue('id_cms') != 11){`
    `return;`
    `return $this->hookDisplayHome($params);}`

in homefeatured.php